# How to search for complete SKU like "K-00019" (without splitting it at "-" and without removing leading zeros)

Tags: 7, commerce, search

I am using Search API to search commerce products by SKU. But when I enter "K-00019" as search string, every item is retrieved that contains "19". I investigated why this happens and found, that a method called "prepareKeys" splits the string K-00019 into two parts: K and 00019, then ignores the first part (letter K) and transforms the second part to 19 because of leading zeroes.
As you can mention, this behaviour leads to way too much results.
I need a search that allows to search for the complete sku. Do you have an idea how I can accomplish this? I do not have to necessary use Search API, if you have another suggestion, it would be perfectly fine, even a workaround would be okay.

Comment: Are you only searching for SKUs? If so, I think you can change the index for that field to be regular text instead of being included in the keyword search and change the search box to be an exposed filter just for the SKU field.

Comment: No, I am searching for multiple fields, but as a workaround I could cotton up to this, just adding a second search-field for SKU only. But can you explain a little bit more what you mean? Where can I change the index? What I already did: under /admin/config/search/search_api/index/product_display/fields I changed the type of the SKU field from fulltext to string, without success. In which place I can do your suggestion?

Comment: If you change the type of the SKU field to string then it won't be included in the fulltext search. You need to add another exposed filter to the form just for the SKU.

Comment: Ok, I understand: you mean I am not searching the index but a "standard" views query. Meanwhile I made a workaround, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I made a workaround: I added a computed field to the product type , copying the SKU, removing the dash/hyphen and saving this value. Instead of including the real SKU in the index, I included this stripped version.
At the form part, I added a validation function that removes dashes/hypens from the search input automatically. Just for sake of documentation:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'sku_search_validate';
  }

function sku_search_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($form_state['values']['my_sku']) && !empty($form_state['values']['my_sku'])) {
    $new_value = str_replace('-', '', $form_state['values']['my_sku']);
    $form['my_sku']['#parents'] = array('my_sku');
    form_set_value($form['my_sku'], $new_value, $form_state);
  }
}
```